# How to merge array from different array

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections

Hi i have problem with merge array,

How to merge array from different array

From Here

Array 1

```
array:6 [
  "patient_name" => "Pasien 4"
  "employee_no" => "1114"
  "birth_date" => "1990-05-02"
  "gender" => "L"
  "department_code" => "D0004"
  "section_code" => "S0004"
]
```

Array 2

```
 array:2 [
  "kd_layan" => "10000104  "
  "nama_layan" => "PAKET MCU ADVANCE (MALE)"
]
```

To Here

```
array:8 [
  "patient_name" => "Pasien 4"
  "employee_no" => "1114"
  "birth_date" => "1990-05-02"
  "gender" => "L"
  "department_code" => "D0004"
  "section_code" => "S0004"
  "kd_layan" => "10000104  "
  "nama_layan" => "PAKET MCU ADVANCE (MALE)"
]
```

Any solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: See this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_func_array_merge

Comment: as per your link : https://pastebin.com/J9BjV91x. you want to merge first 4 records with last 4  records?

Comment: And also show code that how you get this arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has very simple solution using `array_merge()` function of php.
`array_merge()` function merges one or more arrays into one array.

You can assign one array to the function, or as many as you like.
If two or more array elements have the same key, the last one overrides the others.

in your case use it as below

```
$arr1=[
    "patient_name" => "Pasien 4",
    "employee_no" => "1114",
    "birth_date" => "1990-05-02",
    "gender" => "L",
    "department_code" => "D0004",
    "section_code" => "S0004"
];
$arr2=[
    "kd_layan" => "10000104  ",
    "nama_layan" => "PAKET MCU ADVANCE (MALE)"
];

print_r(array_merge($arr1,$arr2));
```

for more see [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score 1):

use `array_merge` to merge two array

```
$array1 = [
  "patient_name" => "Pasien 4",
  "employee_no" => "1114",
  "birth_date" => "1990-05-02",
  "gender" => "L",
  "department_code" => "D0004",
  "section_code" => "S0004",
];

$array2 = [
  "kd_layan" => "10000104",
  "nama_layan" => "PAKET MCU ADVANCE (MALE)"
];

$res = array_merge($array1, $array2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

check [demo code](https://3v4l.org/TWMs9)

Comment: Hi thanks from answer but from this case here is my all structure data

https://pastebin.com/J9BjV91x

How to merge data from every data from array to above

Comment: You should have something common to merge one array to that particular another array. otherwise, how can we predict that the first array will merge with forth. you should have something that are common in the array. Or if possible make it using join query, :)

Comment: The answer you've selected is the same answer of mine and I posted first. then why you selected his answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()`

It merges one or more arrays into one array.

Syntax : `array_merge(array1, array2, array3, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

use `array_merge`

```
$arr1 =  [
  "patient_name" => "Pasien 4"
  "employee_no" => "1114"
  "birth_date" => "1990-05-02"
  "gender" => "L"
  "department_code" => "D0004"
  "section_code" => "S0004"
]

 arr2 = [
  "kd_layan" => "10000104  "
  "nama_layan" => "PAKET MCU ADVANCE (MALE)"
]

$result  = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below i have mention an example which will merge two array and the output will be as it is as you want.

```
$a = array('1' => 'one','2' => 'two');

$b = array('3' => 'three','4' => 'four');

$c = ($a + $b);

print_r($c);
```